# Installed the flask_sqlalchemy module but still got the same Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on code from **CS50 Beyond**... online course available on *YouTube By Prof.Brian Yu*
This code is from Lecture ORM and API in *models.py* file.

I don't understand this error

```
(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ export FLASK_APP=application.py 
(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ python3.7 application.py 
(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ flask run
* Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pglab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/pglab/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2/application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import *
  File "/home/pglab/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

I check all the settings also,

```
(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ python3.7 -m flask --version
Python 3.7.4
Flask 1.1.1
Werkzeug 0.16.0

(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ pip install Flask
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /home/pglab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.1)

(venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /home/pglab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.13)
```

Everything seems fine! I run my flask app many times, but when i started ORM programs in flask things becomes messy....

Can somebody please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have installed the SQLalchemy outside the virtual environment.
please install it after activating the virtual environment then only the virtual environment is able to search the modules.
the main reason is the virtual environment scope is limited its not global

please follow below command

```
source/bin/activate   //this will virtual enviroment
sudo pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1 // this will install the packge within your virtual envoronment
```

Comment: I am already in (venv), the second command returns the same output as above.

Comment: (venv) (base) pglab@pglab15:~/Downloads/Compressed/orms_and_apis/airline2$ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in /home/pglab/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1) (1.3.13)

Comment: Have you installed sqlalchemy?if not please try   -> pip install    SQLAlchemy==1.3.12

Answer (score 0):

To the get the Flask wrapper for SQLAlchemy, do

```
python3 -m pip install flask-sqlalchemy
```

instead of

```
python3 -m pip install sqlalchemy
```

Or, since you already have SQLAlchemy installed, doing the former will suffice.